# Why is MYSQL Explain Showing Nearly Twice the Number of Rows

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, rows, explain

I have a table called runner, it has 1159082 rows. If I do this :
SELECT count(*) from runner 
WHERE raceid between 20010300 AND 20030399;
I get  10999, exactly as expected. However, if I run an explain on that query I get:
[image: Query Explain plan]

Why is the number of rows processed 20.98k? There are only 10999 rows in that range, where did the others come from? There's no join that could have gone wrong. I have tried it with a small table and the number of rows is correct but in this big one it's wrong. Could it be because the raceid is not sequential?

Comment: Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123430/why-in-explain-in-mysql-row-count-is-very-high help?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nico,
Yes, that does answer the question. I did some more experiments and found that as soon as an extra column was added outside of the index the estimated rows doubled. From reading that post I'm guessing it doesn't really matter much but the query performance seems to have dropped through the floor all of a sudden, hence my reason for looking at the explain. I'll need to go back and look at it again.
Thanks for your help.